# Is this flux residue or the PCB is burnt?

Tags: pcb

I bought a new laptop, and when I was about to add an SSD, I saw this. The store tells me it's nothing, and if anything, just flux residue from production.

To me, it looks like overheating. That is; a bad connection or something is causing a lot of heat, and thus these brown and dark spots around, especially the leftmost pin, and a black area on the edge of the PCB.

What do you think? Doesn't it look like it is burnt?

[image]

[image]

**ADDED:**

Let me add an extreme close up for details:
http://amews.net/ExtremeCloseUp.png

What about the edge - seems like it has been damaged (not a sharp edge anymore) - does that matter?

What about the brown color on the connector itself ? I suppose that the connector would not be plugged in while soldering. How should flux end up there then?

http://amews.net/Edge2.jpg

Comment: What make is it- Just curious. Seems like a quick job or new employee . lol

Comment: Asus *padding to get enough characters :P *

Comment: Looks AFU (all fluxed up).

Comment: Ah, man, it is just flux residue with resin. If there was enough heat to burn it up, that is enough current to burn it up, that cable would be all black! Also, the traces are in a very fine condition, so it is just flux residue, that's all. If you do not accept the answers of this community, then why ask, anyways?

Comment: That was an answer to the new images? How did flux end up on a connected cable? And what about the "scraped" edge - does that matter? I will accept, I'd just like some last comments on these two questions. I forgot to ask in the first place.

Comment: @user1797930 I don't mean accept by clicking, I don't care about that. But you are not satisfied.. And yes, that flux splashes everywhere if you find the right amount of solder and speed..

Comment: I wasn't talking about accepting by clicking either :)  I can understand flux will splash everywhere, I just don't see how it could end up on a connector, since I assume that wasn't plugged in while soldering. Should I worry about the scraped edge?

Comment: I know you have other things to do than answering my questions over and over again :) But could I please get a last comment on my comment above?

Comment: A final comment? Yeah, it's flux.

Comment: @Samuel Well, I meant a comment on "Should I worry about the scraped edge?" (See amews.net/ExtremeCloseUp.png) - I guess that is not flux, but does it matter when it's just at the edge?

Comment: As you may have guessed, I am new here. What is the proper way to close this question ? I mean all answers are most likely correct, so which one to accept by clicking ? Asking in case it gives a better reputation to the one who gave that answer.

Answer (score 11):

This board was probably manufactured in a part of the world where the labor rate is low.  As a result, manufacturers have more flexibility in trading off costs in getting everything right up front versus having to fix a few things afterwards.

Your pictures aren't very good, but it looks like flux residue.  This is common when hand rework is performed.  If this is rosin flux, which is sortof looks like, it's totally harmless.  It's basically like epoxy or low grade amber.

Does the product work correctly.  If so, I would leave it alone.  If it really bothers you, try swabbing the area with a cotton swab dampened with isopropyl alchohol.

Comment: By the pictures not being very good, do you just mean the quality, or that the PCB looks bad ?  Same question for you as to the others: What about the discoleration of the very edge of the PCB (red circle on first image) ? Can flux also cause that? I thought it was heat spreading around the pins.

Comment: And yes it does work fine so far - I'm just worried that it could be heat related, and thus causing issues over time.

Comment: @user: I was referring to the poor photography, making it hard to tell what is really going on.  It's hard to see the stuff on the edge, but it could be just excess flux that dribbled down.  It looks like whoever did the rework used large quantities of flux.

Comment: And that was exactly my question. Flux dribbling down can cause decoloration even on the edge ? It seems that where the edge is black, it is kind of shiny in contrast to where it isn't black. I guess that's a clue of it being flux, and not burned?

Comment: @user1797930 Yes, that discoloration across edge would be flux  - the heat that charred the flux is when the connector was soldered by hand, also shows the uneven soldering. Could be refurbished PCB so manual soldering.

Comment: It's brand new, so a refurbished motherboard would be disappointing. I guess it could also just be the automatic soldering not being good at that spot, and then they manually fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

It just looks like flux. You've already been running it right? Just run it for awhile, power down, and quickly feel this spot. If it's getting hot enough to turn the PCB brown then you'll know damn quick if overheating is the issue or not.

Additionally, you can make sure the battery and power are disconnected and then clean this spot with some isopropyl alcohol on an old toothbrush or paintbrush. Flux should come right off.

Comment: *Paint Thinner* works great for flux :)

Comment: I always thought of flux residue as a clear solid substance on the PCB - not this brown color. Can flux be brown like this? And also, what about the edge of the PCB? Can flux cause it to be discolered like that as well ? Clean it ? That would cancel the warrenty - so I don't want to do so :)

Comment: As example I thought flux looked like this http://www.robotroom.com/Capacitor-Self-Discharge/Flux-residue-fibers-and-other-contaminants.jpg  and not brown as in this case ?

Comment: Definitely FLUX. If it were burning (PCB or Cable) you would smell it and see a thick grey smoke- It smells like concentrated burning plastic smell and stays with you for days.. blerghh *cough*

Comment: I don't see clear flux very often. For all the solder I've used it's this same brown color. It will depend on the solder and the amount of heat applied. Typically, hand soldering leaves brown (burned) flux.

I highly doubt that cleaning flux will void your warranty. But it leaving it won't harm anything either, so whatever you prefer.

Comment: Questions: 1: And you also believe flux could leave this black discoloring of the very edge of the PCB (first image - red circle) ? 2: You say I would smell it if it was burning, but what if it is just overheating - might not create smoke I guess ? 3: How much heat does it take to leave such burn marks on PCB ?

Comment: I thought of the edge as heat spreading around that pin, causing the edge to darken.

Comment: @abdullahkahraman "Paint Thinner works great for flux :)" -- Be careful, paint thinner is a generic term that sometimes includes things like acetone.  Acetone will dissolve plastic.

Comment: @user1797930 Yes, it can get on the edge. Flux is often added by technicians assembling boards. A new or overzealous tech could have easily gotten flux all over the edge. You seem rather persistent that this discoloration isn't flux, are you in danger of losing a bet or something? I think it's flux, no need to ask again.

Comment: No I'm not insisting that it isn't flux, just worried - and hearing an answer for a very specific question (the edge for instance) makes me more calm. I guess I should believe you when you all say the same. Although I'm still curious how much heat does it usually take to leave burn marks on a PCB ?

Comment: @JimParis Yeah, this one is called "*Cellulosic Thinner*". And I think it eats the plastic, so yes, one should be very careful :)

Comment: I added two pictures with a question about each - could I please get your comment on that ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like flux residue. I'd try to clean it off with some isopropyl alcohol. Is the board still working fine?

Comment: Yes it works fine. Same question for you: What about the discoleration of the very edge of the PCB (red circle on first image) ? Can flux also cause that? I thought it was heat spreading around the pins.

Comment: I've use CRAMOLIN FLUX-OFF spray to remove flux residue. But one need to be very careful: FLUX-OFF dissolve plastic details...

Comment: It's hard to tell from the photo but it looks like an excessive amount of flux that ran over the edge of the board. If you want to clean it off take a cotton swab with a bit of IPA and see if you can remove it. Really though, as long as the board continues to work I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like flux, also looks like a badly installed connector :)  A little hard to see in the pic though.

Comment: Badly installed connector ? And you say flux ? What about the dark edge of the PCB ? Can flux cause that? Isn't it burned?

Comment: @user1797930 The FPC ribbon connector at the right side, next to your connector. And yeah, it looks like flux that needs cleaning off.

Comment: I thought flux residue looked like this: http://www.robotroom.com/Capacitor-Self-Discharge/Flux-residue-fibers-and-other-contaminants.jpg .  I can't really find examples of flux residue having this brown/black color. Are you sure that's normal ? And also, can flux cause this miscoloring of the edge of the PCB ? I thought of that as heat spreading around that pin, causing the edge to darken.

Comment: @user1797930 have a look at [this](http://www.emsciences.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/images/board-with-flux.jpg)

Comment: but again, the brown residue is only on the solder, not on the PCB - on the PCB it's clear.

Comment: It's just easier to see the brown tint against silver.   That picture you posted with the brown residue on the PCB looks exactly like flux residue from hand soldering a connector.  It turns that color, it looks that consistency, it can run out onto the board and even over the edge.  I've see it 100 times, so have the other guys commenting here :)

Comment: Like this photo http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/6694/burntflux.jpg  or this one http://164.58.173.38/marantz/2230board.jpg

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that very accurate answer - i really do :) Maybe you could comment on the added images and questions to the original question? That is; How did flux end up on a connected cable? And what about the "scraped" edge - does that matter? I promise not to bother you with further questions regarding this issue after getting a comment on these :) About your image examples, I have still not seen any cases with the edge discolored, but from your answers I believe that it is also just flux.

Comment: @user1797930, there are different type of fluxes. Fluxes, containing rosin, usually become darker when heated. But synthetical fluxes may stay transparent after heat is put away.

Comment: @GeorgeGaál And when you say heated you mean from the soldering process - not from the board heating up ?

Comment: @user1797930 Yes, of course. Also I don't see any "hot" elements on board from photo of TS.

Answer (score 1):

I think that notebook was repaired at manufacturer's plant. Manufacturer for board processing purposes uses no-clean fluxes or manufacturer can put all board into cleaning ultrasonic bath and wash out all flux residues. So such marks are usually left, when service engineer repairs board with common flux and common soldering iron... Also we can see on photo that the corner of board is damaged. It is the trace of using of soldering iron and maybe desoldering wick. When one use desoldering wick, it scrubs the top layer of board. And it may be damaged.

Comment: So what are you saying? The board is damaged, or nothing serious to worry about ?

Comment: The top layer of board is damaged a little. But don't worry. The important thing that all signal traces are intact and working.

Comment: So you are basically saying the same as everyone else here? That I should not worry about this causing the board to quit after short time of use? That it is only a cosmetic issue, and I should just enjoy the system instead of worrying about this?

Comment: I think that yes. The only thing that can make problems in future is soldered connector. The solder joints doesn't look very reliable and good. If you can prove to seller that notebook was repaired, it is one case. You need to check original warranty labels and screw heads. But if you don't think so or can't prove your opinion, the only way is to relax, enjoy the system and never mind it :-)