# Lithium batteries worries

Tags: safety, protection, lithium-ion, short-circuit

For the last few days I have had this strange fear that an external short circuit would cause an explosive fire of my laptop's Li-ion battery.

Three questions:

1. Is it true that lithium ion batteries have protections inside, so that an external short circuit would not cause overheating + explosion (even if you directly connect the +/- terminals on the laptop battery) ?
2. My fear started from the pictures shown in this thread: [Is this flux residue or the PCB is burnt?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48482/is-this-flux-residue-or-the-pcb-is-burnt). I worry that the possible repair performed on this motherboard by the factory could be bad, and thus cause a short circuit that would result in overheating+fire in the battery. I have kind of accepted that the brown substance is just flux, but what about the soldering itself. Do you think the risk of a short circuit is higher than normal, considering what's seen on the pictures? Or is it completely unthinkable ?
3. Are you certain that I should simply forget all about this worry?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Yes, laptop batteries do.
2.) No, a short circuit is not more likely. No, it's not completely unthinkable, just like it's not unthinkable that you'll get hit by a meteorite. It's just highly unlikely.
3.) Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Samuel's answers but would like to add that short circuits are rare on PCBs unless there is a process or design error causing it to warp and short.  Intermittent shorts misssed out are not usually visible and in buried layers and end up being around 1 ohm which is high enough so you can fuse it open with a high current power supply, but not low enough to cause excessive heat in the battery.

A bigger worry with flux and especially tracks with no solder mask can corrode and become leaky enough to cause functional failure.

Take a look at this 16 mos old Mac Air which got wet and then dried with a fan. This photo was taken after one week after getting rained on. ( No we don't have acid rain)
[image]

My explanation is that Apple's Mfg uses "no clean" flux which does not require removal or else they cut cost corners on this process. I suspect it had significant dust inside which dissolved after rain leaked thru the keyboard then mixed with the flux and then corroded and then the corrosion spread everywhere within a day. The fan was used next day. We won't mention which grandchild left it outside on the table.

The leakage might only be as low as a few kilo ohm which is certain enough to kill the circuits but not destroy the battery.

**Lesson learnt**
Take 3 ingredients each which are insulators and let oxygen do it's work and you get copper rust.

> **Don't take it to the beach, stay out of humid areas. Keep it dry !**

I might try to cleanse it and restore its function and blog later.

Comment: That would be worth attempting a repair on if you were in low earth orbit or beyond and/or your life utterly depended on it - and even then you'd be better off spending the time on last farewells. . The chances of success are about zero